# share variable between activities A and C (A -> B -> C)

Tags: android, android-intent

As it'is written in the title I want share a variable between the activities A and C without retrieving this variable in activity B ? is it possible ?

I want to have something like that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
intent.putExtra(variableA, variableC);
```

... (what should I write here)

Actually My App is doing that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: use shared preferences, its easy and you can get the value even from a alarm and service.

Comment: @enzo why you don't simple use Shared Preferences?
See this please, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

If you're using the variable only in Activities A & C why pass it inside the Intent to Activity B?

Answer (score 0):

Intent.putExtra works like an HashMap, with the key/value logic. First argument is the key. The key has to unique . If you try to store different values with the same key only the last value will be inserted.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
    intent.putExtra("variableAKey", variableA);
    intent.putExtra("variableCKey", variableC);
```

When the onCreate of the destination activity is invoked, you can retrieve the values in this way:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getIntExtra("variableAKey");
```

if `variableA` is a `int`. Intent have a getter for the primitive type and String and serilizable/parcelable objects as well. You should refer the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: thnx for your answer. Actually what i want do is just share one variable between activities A and C whithout retrieving this varible in activity B ?

Comment: the you should only retrieve inside C.

Comment: i can't passe a variable from the activity A to the activity C

Comment: well in activity A i wrote this :  Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class); intent.putExtra("variableAKey", variableA);

Comment: Intent intent = getIntent();
String varA = intent.getIntExtra("variableAKey"); Log.d("tag",varA);

Comment: you should use getStringExtra in order to retrieve strings. Also you should read the doc when somebody lonk it you