# Shared preferences for creating one time activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have three activities A, B and C where A and B are forms and after filling and saving the form data in database (SQLite). I am using intent from A to B and then B to C. What I want is that every time I open my app I want C as my home screen and not A and B anymore.

I guess shared preferences would work for this, but I cannot find a good example to give me a starting place.

Comment: [Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) from Android dev site.

Comment: Did you look at the Official tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref ?

Answer (score 692, accepted):

#### Setting values in Preference:

```
// MY_PREFS_NAME - a static String variable like: 
//public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "Elena");
 editor.putInt("idName", 12);
 editor.apply();
```

#### Retrieve data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
int idName = prefs.getInt("idName", 0); //0 is the default value.
```

More info:

[**Using Shared Preferences**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

[**Shared Preferences**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Consider using apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background.

Comment: `apply()` is asynchronous call to perform disk I/O where as `commit()` is synchronous. So avoid calling `commit()` from the UI thread.

Answer (score 52):

**How to Intialize?**

```
// 0 - for private mode`
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 

Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**How to Store Data In Shared Preference?**

```
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
```

OR

```
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); //Storing integer
```

And don't forget to apply :

```
editor.apply();
```

**How to retrieve Data From Shared Preferences ?**

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String

pref.getInt("key_name", 0); // getting Integer
```

Hope this will Help U :)

Comment: The initialization is important if you accessing in an activity, fragment or public class

Answer (score 26):

You can create your custom SharedPreference class

```
public class YourPreference {   
    private static YourPreference yourPreference;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public static YourPreference getInstance(Context context) {
        if (yourPreference == null) {
            yourPreference = new YourPreference(context);
        }
        return yourPreference;
    }

    private YourPreference(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YourCustomNamedPreference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void saveData(String key,String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsEditor .putString(key, value);
        prefsEditor.commit();           
    }

    public String getData(String key) {
        if (sharedPreferences!= null) {
           return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
        }
        return "";         
    }
}
```

You can get YourPrefrence instance like:

```
YourPreference yourPrefrence = YourPreference.getInstance(context);
yourPreference.saveData(YOUR_KEY,YOUR_VALUE);

String value = yourPreference.getData(YOUR_KEY);
```

Comment: String value = yourPreference.getData(YOUR_KEY); Error :non static content canot be refered in static context

Comment: hi instance of Context was giving me null so I have putted sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YourCustomNamedPreference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
this line in try catch block and its work but the thing is that why it giving null?

Comment: I use this class in my project and init my sharedpreferences in BaseActivity, and use in other activities (splashScreen & login & main activity) for check user login state and exit from app. But this don't work for android 8 for exit! Are you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 21):

I just found all the above examples just too confusing, so I wrote my own. Code fragments are fine if you know what you're doing, but what about people like me who don't?

Want a cut-n-paste solution instead?  Well here it is!

Create a new java file and call it Keystore.  Then paste in this code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;

public class Keystore { //Did you remember to vote up my example?
    private static Keystore store;
    private SharedPreferences SP;
    private static String filename="Keys";

private Keystore(Context context) {
    SP = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
}

public static Keystore getInstance(Context context) {
    if (store == null) {
        Log.v("Keystore","NEW STORE");
        store = new Keystore(context);
    }
    return store;
}

public void put(String key, String value) {//Log.v("Keystore","PUT "+key+" "+value);
    Editor editor = SP.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit(); // Stop everything and do an immediate save!
    // editor.apply();//Keep going and save when you are not busy - Available only in APIs 9 and above.  This is the preferred way of saving.
}

public String get(String key) {//Log.v("Keystore","GET from "+key);
    return SP.getString(key, null);

}

public int getInt(String key) {//Log.v("Keystore","GET INT from "+key);
    return SP.getInt(key, 0);
}

public void putInt(String key, int num) {//Log.v("Keystore","PUT INT "+key+" "+String.valueOf(num));
    Editor editor = SP.edit();

    editor.putInt(key, num);
    editor.commit();
}


public void clear(){ // Delete all shared preferences
    Editor editor = SP.edit();

    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

public void remove(){ // Delete only the shared preference that you want
    Editor editor = SP.edit();

    editor.remove(filename);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Now save that file and forget about it.  You're done with it. Now go back into your activity and use it like this:

```
public class YourClass extends Activity{

private Keystore store;//Holds our key pairs

public YourSub(Context context){
    store = Keystore.getInstance(context);//Creates or Gets our key pairs.  You MUST have access to current context!

    int= store.getInt("key name to get int value");
    string = store.get("key name to get string value");

    store.putInt("key name to store int value",int_var);
    store.put("key name to store string value",string_var);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this class in my project and init my sharedpreferences in BaseActivity, and use in other activities (splashScreen & login & main activity) for check user login state and exit from app. But this don't work for android 8 for exit! Are you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

**`Shared Preferences`** are XML files to store private primitive data in key-value pairs. Data Types include *Booleans*, *floats*, *ints*, *longs*, and *strings*.

When we want to save some data which is accessible throughout the application, one way to do is to save it in global variable. But it will vanish once the application is closed. Another and recommended way is to save in `SharedPreference`. Data saved in SharedPreferences file is accessible throughout the application and persists even after the application closes or across reboots.

**SharedPreferences** saves the data in key-value pair and can be accessed in same fashion.

You can create Object of **`SharedPreferences`** using two methods,

1).**getSharedPreferences()** : Using this methods you can create Multiple   SharedPreferences.and its first parameters in name of `SharedPreferences`.

2).**getPreferences()** : Using this method you can create Single `SharedPreferences`.

**Storing Data**

Add a Variable declaration/ Create Preference File

```
public static final String PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = "MyAppPreferences";
```

Retrieve a handle to filename (using getSharedPreferences)

```
SharedPreferences settingsfile= getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME,0);
```

**Open Editor and Add key-value pairs**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor myeditor = settingsfile.edit(); 
myeditor.putBoolean("IITAMIYO", true); 
myeditor.putFloat("VOLUME", 0.7)
myeditor.putInt("BORDER", 2)
myeditor.putLong("SIZE", 12345678910L)
myeditor.putString("Name", "Amiyo")
myeditor.apply();
```

Don’t forget to apply/save using `myeditor.apply()` as shown above.

**Retrieving Data**

```
 SharedPreferences mysettings= getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME, 0);
IITAMIYO = mysettings.getBoolean("IITAMIYO", false); 
//returns value for the given key. 
//second parameter gives the default value if no user preference found
// (set to false in above case)
VOLUME = mysettings.getFloat("VOLUME", 0.5) 
//0.5 being the default value if no volume preferences found
// and similarly there are get methods for other data types
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public class Preferences {

public static final String PREF_NAME = "your preferences name";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE;

public static final String USER_ID = "USER_ID_NEW";
public static final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";

public static final String NAME = "NAME";
public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
public static final String PHONE = "PHONE";
public static final String address = "address";

public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key,
        boolean defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

}

public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

}

public static String readString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
    getEditor(context).putFloat(key, value).commit();
}

public static float readFloat(Context context, String key, float defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getFloat(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeLong(Context context, String key, long value) {
    getEditor(context).putLong(key, value).commit();
}

public static long readLong(Context context, String key, long defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getLong(key, defValue);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
}

public static Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}

}
```

****Use Preferences to Write value using:-****

```
Preferences.writeString(getApplicationContext(),
                    Preferences.NAME, "dev");
```

****Use  Preferences to Read value using:-****

```
Preferences.readString(getApplicationContext(), Preferences.NAME,
                    "");
```

Answer (score 8):

Best way to create `SharedPreference` and for global usage you need to create a class like below:

```
public class PreferenceHelperDemo {
    private final SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    public PreferenceHelperDemo(Context context) {
        mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    private String PREF_Key= "Key";

    public String getKey() {
        String str = mPrefs.getString(PREF_Key, "");
        return str;
    }

    public void setKey(String pREF_Key) {
        Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mEditor.putString(PREF_Key, pREF_Key);
        mEditor.apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

```
SharedPreferences mPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public SharedPrefrences(Context mContext) {
    mPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SharedPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor=mPref.edit();
}

public void setLocation(String latitude, String longitude) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();
    editor.putString("latitude", latitude);
    editor.putString("longitude", longitude);
    editor.apply();
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return mPref.getString("latitude", "");
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return mPref.getString("longitude", "");
}

public void setGCM(String gcm_id, String device_id) {
     editor.putString("gcm_id", gcm_id);
    editor.putString("device_id", device_id);
    editor.apply();
}

public String getGCMId() {
    return mPref.getString("gcm_id", "");
}

public String getDeviceId() {
    return mPref.getString("device_id", "");
}


public void setUserData(User user){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);
    editor.putString("user", json);
    editor.apply();
}
public User getUserData(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPref.getString("user", "");
    User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
    return user;
}

public void setSocialMediaStatus(SocialMedialStatus status){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(status);
    editor.putString("status", json);
    editor.apply();
}
public SocialMedialStatus getSocialMediaStatus(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPref.getString("status", "");
    SocialMedialStatus status = gson.fromJson(json, SocialMedialStatus.class);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Write to Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
 editor.commit();
```

**Read from Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Comment: Use
getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
instead of:
getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Because the data will only be valid for the activity you are on. This is because in this activity the file name is on the activity name and so if you call on this preferences from another activity the data will be different.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain how to use the code you provided and why it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at a past [sample project](https://github.com/toubou91/SharedPreferencesSample) of mine, written for this purpose.  I saves locally a name and retrieves it either upon a user's request or when the app starts.

But, at this time, it would be better to use `commit` (instead of `apply`) for persisting the data. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960678/whats-the-difference-between-commit-and-apply-in-shared-preference).

Answer (score 0):

```
Initialise here..
 SharedPreferences msharedpref = getSharedPreferences("msh",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = msharedpref.edit();

store data...
editor.putString("id",uida); //uida is your string to be stored
editor.commit();
finish();


fetch...
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("msh", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        uida = prefs.getString("id", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences is so easy to learn, so take a look on this 
simple tutorial about [sharedpreference](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-sharedpreferences-example.html)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

    public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Create object of SharedPreferences.
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);

        //now get Editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        //put your value
        editor.putString("name", required_Text);

        //commits your edits
        editor.commit();

       // Its used to retrieve data
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
       String name = sharedPref.getString("name", "");

       if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("required_Text")) {
          Log.v("Matched","Required Text Matched");
          } else {
               Log.v("Not Matched","Required Text Not Matched"); 
                 }
```